# Set cell color in Angular UI grid based on subsequent column value

Tags: angularjs, cell, angular-ui-grid

I'd like to set the color of each ui-grid cell based on the subsequent/previous cell from the same row

I added the following to the ColumnDef parameter in the grid object

```
    columnDefs: [
  {field: 'P1Pin', displayName: 'P1 Pin', width: "25%", cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
    if (grid.getCellValue(row,col) == grid.getCellValue(row,col+1)) return 'failing';
  }},
```

If I replace grid.getCellValue(row,col+1) to a constant (like 37), the cell color is set. However the current cell should be colored based on the subsequent cell from the same row.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the behavior of grid.getCellValue(0,2) on a 2 column table?

Comment: @kpie - I assumed it should return the 0th row, 3rd col' cell value. But are they indexed from 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

Using the row object achieves my requirement

```
 columnDefs: [
  {field: 'P1Pin', displayName: 'R1 Data Pin', width: "25%", cellClass: function (grid, row) {
    if(row.entity.P1Pin != row.entity.P2Pin)
    return 'failing';
  }},
```

Though, I dont get the grid object usage. Will be great if someone can explain on this.
Thanks.